# How to edit Django models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Let's say that I have some data on my model and that I want to edit it, how can I do that without deleting the model or recreating a new one like I would do it on the admin panel?

Comment: Change whatever you want in your `models.Model` class in `models.py` and then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Make the changes to the model class. Then you would need to generate/create [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/) for the models to apply the changes.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add/remove fields on the model?

Comment: @Countour-Integral I was talking about the data not the model itself like to edit it. We can put new data by saving it but how to edit existing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automate something large (like changing each value that is null) outside of the panel, you'll have to manually insert the columns by using `python manage.py shell`.

Let's say that you have a `models.Model` inherited class named `myModel`, that you later decide to add a new column called `b`.

Your class is defined as:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    a = models.TextField(max_length=20, null=True)
    b = models.TextField(max_length=20, null=True) # this is added later
```

Now what you'll have to do is run `python manage.py shell` and do the following

```
>>> from app.models import myModel # I assmue your app is named app
>>> myModel.objects.all() # All the previous models that were created
<QuerySet [<myModel: myModel object (1)>]>
>>> for model in myModel.objects.all():
...     if not model.b:
...             model.b = "THIS WAS NULL, NOW IT ISN'T" # modify as you wish
...             model.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problema correctly an easy way to edit your data would be to add you model to the admin with the fields you would like to alter and edit them, in your app's admin.py add something like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from youapp.models import MyModel

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  pass
```

And then just run your project and update it manually via the admin, another option would be to use the django shell or create custom migrations

ps: Usually you can access the admin at http://localhost:8000/admin

You might need to create a superuser, run `python manage.py createsuperuser` and follow the instructions

[Django Admin Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/)